# How can i delete a person group name that I no longer require within the face api?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, uipath, face-api

I'm using UiPath automation software to connect to Face API via Azure Cognitive Service.

I want to delete a person group name that I no longer require but I've tried to use the documentation to advise how to delete however it's requesting for a persongroupid which I don't have one apart from the person group name.

Please help me how this can be resolved as soon as possible.

Comment: I tried to set up Azure Cognitive Service too and didn't manage to set it up. however I used python libraries instead : face_recognition, cv2 and numpy

Comment: Could you please share the link to the sample that you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a person from person group you would need to get the person group id first and then delete the person from the group. To get the person group id use the [person group list](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395248) API.

Note the person group id from the response. Use the above id in the [PersonGroup person list API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395241) and use the person id from the response in the [PersonGroup_person delete](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523d) API.